# Element is not clickable issue Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I have looked up the similar problems but could not find a solution at all. I have even tried Thread.sleep but it did not work either.
I still get the

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60WNq.png)

**"org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element ... is not clickable at point (1322, 246). Other element would receive the click: 
(Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.97)"**  error.

Here is my code ;

```
    //click on relative info
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,20);

   driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.mat-tab-labels>div:nth-child(3)")).click(); 

    //click on representative
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@aria-label=\"Representative\"]//following::span)[1]")).click();
    wait.until( ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated( By.cssSelector(".cdk-overlay-pane") ) );

    //select representative
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"mat-option-73\"]")).click();

    wait.until( ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated( By.cssSelector(".cdk-overlay-pane") ) );
```

Comment: Could you please share the dom structure?

Answer (score 0):

He may have an iframe

If there is an iframe, you need to switch to the iframe

```
driver.switchTo().frame("iframeId");//iframe id or iframe name
```

It’s best to post web code

Comment: Nope this is definitely not correct as it does not have any frame.